# Why doesn't this script print out any graphs? Flot Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

This script below is printing out the checkboxes but isn't plotting anything in the graph window.

```
if (key && allDataSets[key])
                data.push(allDataSets[key]);
```

```
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Flot Examples</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

    <p>Here is an example with real data: military budgets for
        various countries in constant (2005) million US dollars (source: <a href="http://www.sipri.org/">SIPRI</a>).</p>

    <p>Since all data is available client-side, it's pretty easy to
       make the plot interactive. Try turning countries on/off with the
       checkboxes below.</p>

    <p id="choices">Show:</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {


    var Test1 = {
    "date": {
        label: "Date",
        data: [[1, 20110122], [2, 20110123], [3, 20110124], [4, 20110125]]
    },        
    "time": {
        label: "Time",
          data: [[1, 22.12], [2, 22.12], [3, 22.12], [4, 22.12]]
    },
   "modules": {
        label: "Modules",
         data: [[1, 22], [2, 22], [3, 22], [4, 22]]
    }, 
    "cases": {
        label: "Cases",
         data: [[1, 1312], [2, 1312], [3, 1312], [4, 1312]]
    }, 
    "failed": {
        label: "Failed",
          data: [[1, 75], [2, 77], [3, 64], [4, 55]]
    }, 
    "cover": {
        label: "Cover",
data: [[1, 13.55 ], [2, 23.55], [3, 33.55], [4, 43.55]]
    }}; 

var Test2 = {
    "date": {
        label: "Date",
        data: [[1, 20110122], [2, 20110123], [3, 20110124], [4, 20110125]]
    },        
    "time": {
        label: "Time",
          data: [[1, 22.12], [2, 22.12], [3, 22.12], [4, 22.12]]
    },
   "modules": {
        label: "Modules",
         data: [[1, 22], [2, 22], [3, 22], [4, 22]]
    }, 
    "cases": {
        label: "Cases",
         data: [[1, 1312], [2, 1312], [3, 1312], [4, 1312]]
    }, 
    "failed": {
        label: "Failed",
          data: [[1, 75], [2, 77], [3, 64], [4, 55]]
    }, 
    "cover": {
        label: "Cover",
data: [[1, 13.55 ], [2, 23.55], [3, 33.55], [4, 43.55]]
    }}; 

var Test3 = {
    "date": {
        label: "Date",
        data: [[1, 20110122], [2, 20110123], [3, 20110124], [4, 20110125]]
    },        
    "time": {
        label: "Time",
          data: [[1, 22.12], [2, 22.12], [3, 22.12], [4, 22.12]]
    },
   "modules": {
        label: "Modules",
         data: [[1, 22], [2, 22], [3, 22], [4, 22]]
    }, 
    "cases": {
        label: "Cases",
         data: [[1, 1312], [2, 1312], [3, 1312], [4, 1312]]
    }, 
    "failed": {
        label: "Failed",
          data: [[1, 75], [2, 77], [3, 64], [4, 55]]
    }, 
    "cover": {
        label: "errover",
data: [[1, 13.55 ], [2, 23.55], [3, 33.55], [4, 43.55]]
    }};
       var allDataSets = [Test1,Test2,Test3];

    // hard-code color indices to prevent them from shifting as
    // countries are turned on/off
    for(j=0; j<allDataSets.length; j++){//Going through all datasets, are there any other more simple way to do this???
    var i = 0;
    $.each(allDataSets[j], function(key, val) {
        val.color = i;
        ++i;
    });


    // insert checkboxes 
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(allDataSets[j], function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append('<br/><input type="checkbox" name="' + key +
                               '" checked="checked" id="id' + key + '">' +
                                   '<label for="id' + key + '">'
                                    + val.label + '</label>');
        });


/**************************Here the script stops working???**********************/


        choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);


    function plotAccordingToChoices() {
        var data = [];

        choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
            var key = $(this).attr("name");
            if (key && allDataSets[j][key])
                data.push(allDataSets[j][key]);
        });

        if (data.length > 0)
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
                yaxis: { min: 0 },
                xaxis: { tickDecimals: 0 }
            });
    }

    plotAccordingToChoices();
    }
});

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

/**********************EDIT*********************************/
OK so I solved the first issue with was simply replacing allDataSets[key] with allDataSets[j][key]

But as i now uncheck a checkbox I get the following error line 134 allDataSets[...] is null or not an object. Why do I get this error? In other words its this line that is incorrect when I uncheck a checkbox    `if (key && allDataSets[j][key])`

Comment: you may need to use firebug or some debugging tool to get a hint where the error is. I don't think someone wants to help you if you don't provide more information.

Comment: That change you made is not correct, I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things you need to do:

1. Declare that loop variable "j" with the `var` keyword.

   ```
   for(var j=0; j<allDataSets.length; j++) {
   ```
2. All that code after your comment line - the click handler etc - needs to move *out* of that loop.
3. Inside the click handler, the code needs to iterate over "allDataSets" and then look for the key in each one:

   ```
   choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function() {
       var key = $(this).attr("name");
       $.each(allDataSets, function(_, set) {
           if (set[key]) data.push(set[key]);
       });
   });
   ```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VpGnS/1/) is the jsfiddle demonstrating the changes.  You'll note that it looks terrible.  That's because your "allDataSets" re-uses the same keys for each clump.  I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but those changes will at least make *something* show up.

Comment: @Pointy Great, thank you, the thing is that I don't want to print out everythingin all datasets, I was just playing around. I have one more question, Say that I want to plot all three "cover" in the graph, how do I make the key to be "cover"? Thanks =)

Comment: Well the sample code builds all those checkboxes from the names in the array(s).  This with the current code, you'd just uncheck everything but the ones you want.

Comment: @Pointy And do you by any mean know how I can stop "allDataSets" from re-using the same keys? =)

Comment: @Matt well that's easy - just edit the definitions of those "Test" datasets, changing the key names as you see fit.

Comment: @Pointy Oh thank you so much. One more question, is it possible to chose which keys to print out, like for example I only want to print out the "failed" and "cover", so now I have it on the form

    "Test2failed": {
        label: "Failed",
          data: [[1, 301], [2, 454], [3, 43], [4, 125]]
    }, 

etc

Comment: Well you'd probably want to re-work the way that demo page works.  All that stuff with the checkboxes is just there to show how the "flot" API works.  You can just make that call to "$.flot()" with an array of objects you create any way you like.  Thus, you could create an array containing only those two objects, and pass that to "$.flot()", and not worry about all that "key" stuff at all.

Comment: Also, when you get a chance, would mind clicking the big checkmark next to this question and, if your feel it's justified, voting for it?  It's the votes that make psychos like me show up and answer questions around here :-)